# keyboard shortcut for accept hint 'Matching Task" in Netbeans console

Tags: netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any keyboard shortcut for accepting hints 'Matching Task" in Netbeans console?

sss

Answer (score 0):

tab to third part of command window then press enter on command you choose.